# Azure VSTS Builds with angular and Node

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-ad-b2c

I m doing a WebApp with Angular + AD B2C with Msal.js + Node + VsCode, so no web.config used.
So, i do a "build & Release" Definition in Vsts in this steps:

- npm install Angular CLI
- npm install
- run build
- Azure App Service Deploy

So far so good, but when i go to the page the manifest cant be fetch, throw this errors

> - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Manifest fetch failed!
>     at Driver.fetchLatestManifest
> - /manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
> - Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.

for what i look up is becouse the MIME Type of .json is not set by default. This also applies in general to any file that might need a specific MIME Type.

[Link solution with Web.Config](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/)

But i dont have web.config becouse i dont use net.core.

The question is, how can i do this without web.config? or it must be configure in Azure Appserver side?

Comment: `web.config` affects the configuration of the web server, in this case IIS 10 (App Service with Windows web workers). Somebody is serving the **static** files to your browser, right? That sombody is IIS and it needs to know about your MIME types. Just drop in the `web.config` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks! i do this and it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config is needed, but it can be generated through Azure App Service Deploy task, also need to configure web.config parameters for Nodejs app.

1. Select Azure App Service Deploy task
2. Check Generate Web.config option in File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options section.
3. Click … > Choose node as Application framework and specify NodeStartFile.

For MIME issue, you can update web.config file through [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) (`https://{app service name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`), navigate to site\wwwroot, then click Edit Icon for web.config file to update it and Save.